# Ubuntu not detecting office wireless network

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have a strange problem, in that my Ubuntu distribution doesn't detect my office wireless network (it's a new office, so new network). It's strange because my Android mobile can detect the same. I have a Dell laptop and am on 14.04.

Earlier I had installed the wireless driver by doing this:

```
apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
modprobe wl
<reboot>
```

I then read a post which said there might be driver problem, so I did this:

```
apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

After this, curiously, both `modprobe -r b43 ssb wl` and `modprobe wl` failed. Then I restarted and now I don't have any WiFi network.

**=== Update ====**

I thought the following output will help debugging better:

```
~# lspci -nn | grep 0280
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

More importantly, the networks work fine when I boot into Windows 7, so I think the problem is related to Ubuntu drivers only.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43686/discussion-on-question-by-dotslash-ubuntu-not-detecting-office-wireless-network).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was unable to find any solution. Someone recommended to check on which channel the office WiFi was running, but the network admin was too lazy to check that for me. I finally had to purchase a Lexosys nano USB adapter.